# Custom cursor in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cursor-position

I want to add a image as my cursor inside a div, But i want it to hide and have a normal pointer cursor, when the mouse hovers over any of the link inside that div.
I wrote :

```js
var $box = $(".box");
var $myCursor = $("#myCursor");
var button1 = $("#link1");
var button2 = $("#link2");
$box.on("mouseleave",function(){
  $myCursor.hide();
})
$box.mousemove(function(e){
  $myCursor.css('top',e.pageY);
  $myCursor.css('left',e.pageX);
  if (!button1.is(":hover") && (!button2.is(":hover"))){
    $myCursor.show();
  }
  else if(button1.is(":hover") || (button2).is(":hover")){
    $myCursor.hide();
  }
  if(e.clientX<$box.width()*0.5){
        $myCursor.css('transition','transform 1s');
        $myCursor.css('transform','rotate(-270deg)');
        }
        else if(e.clientX>$box.width()*0.5){
        $myCursor.css('transition','transform 1s');
        $myCursor.css('transform','none');
        }

});
```

```css
.box{
  height:100vh;
  background:#ccc;
  padding-top:50px;
  cursor:none;
  
}
button{
  display:block;
  margin:15px auto;
  width:20%;
  padding:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#myCursor{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "box">
  <button id = "link1">Some link</button>
  <button id = "link2">Another Link</button>
  <img id = "myCursor" src = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ahasoft-war/512/sniper_rifle-512.png">
</div>
```

How do i implement this properly?
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you simply do this in CSS only?

Comment: As of now it is unclear what is the problem here. Also you have changed your code and what it does after the initial question. That is not a good idea.

Comment: **You implement this properly by omitting Javascript and using CSS.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple solution is just to adjust the scoping of your selectors:

`var $box = $(".box:not(button)");` so the image switch is called whenever the cursor is not over a button. However in your case you should consider reducing the image size so it's closer to the mouse size - as there's a large overlap of image and button before the mouse pointer itself covers the button.

a more complex solution would involve using arrays to register the button coordinates and dimensions, then using `mousemove` and `each` to constantly check the image coordinate widths against the stored buttons dimensions but depending on what else you've got going on there could be a performance hit.

If you add `pointer-events: none` to the `#myCursor` css you prevent the occasional momentary obscuration of the cursor from the button by the image itself - hence better performance.

```js
var $box = $(".box:not(button)");
var $myCursor = $("#myCursor");
var button1 = $("#link1");
var button2 = $("#link2");
$box.on({
 mouseleave:function(){
       $myCursor.hide();
 },
    mousemove: function(e){
   $myCursor.css({ 'left':e.pageX, 'top':e.pageY });
   if (!button1.is(":hover") && !button2.is(":hover")){
     $myCursor.show();
   } else if(button1.is(":hover") || (button2).is(":hover")){
     $myCursor.hide();
   }
   }
});
```

```css
.box{
  height:100vh;
  background:#ccc;
  padding-top:50px;
  cursor:none;
  
}
button{
  display:block;
  margin:15px auto;
  width:20%;
  padding:10px;
  cursor:pointer;
}
#myCursor{
  position:absolute;
  height:50px;
  width:50px;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "box">
  <button id = "link1">Some link</button>
  <button id = "link2">Another Link</button>
  <img id = "myCursor" src = "https://cdn3.iconfinder.com/data/icons/ahasoft-war/512/sniper_rifle-512.png">
</div>
```

Comment: thanks man, I was looking for something like this :)

Comment: Why do people insist doing stuff with jQuery if it's that much easier to do with CSS, while also being much better performance-wise?

Comment: valid point @connexo, personally I'm still learning js/jq and so this exercise assists.

Answer (score 1):

Much easier to achieve using CSS only. You will have to resize the cursor image beforehand, in this example I resized one to 50x50 pixels (the other in the white box is 64x64).

The `, auto` is mandatory and defines a fallback.

```css
.box{
  height:100vh;
  background:#ccc;
  padding-top:50px;
  cursor: url(//codestylers.de/rifle.png), auto;
}
button{
  display:block;
  margin:15px auto;
  width:20%;
  padding:10px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.another-cursor {
  background-color: white;
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  cursor: url(//codestylers.de/cursor.png), auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class = "box">
  <button id = "link1">Some link</button>
  <button id = "link2">Another Link</button>
  <div class="another-cursor"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: my screen is blinking when I run this code and hover

Comment: Mine is not. Windows 8.1, latest Firefox.

Comment: I am using the latest chrome, Sierra mac Pro

Comment: And he is rotating the default cursor using jquery

Comment: I have added a white box that yields a different cursor. Are you experiencing the blinking there as well? The rotating has been edited later on. I don't care about that as it's trivial to do in CSS only (it's actuallly being done using CSS via jQuery already).

Comment: Yes still happening. my graphic card is strong enough

Comment: No blinking on my Mac (latest Sierra, latest Chrome). Neither on Firefox.

Comment: Yeah right, he changed the code, I don't even understand what he wants to achieve. it seems working

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this using CSS, there is no need for javascript.
Have a look here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp

You might set CSS classes with help of javascript to enable some sort of dependency to other elements.